# How can I use Ant & InnoSetup to place a directory at installation for JavaFX

Tags: ant, inno-setup, javafx-8

I am working on bundling an application as an EXE using INNO SETUP.  I have it working, except for one thing.

My project structure looks like this:

```
src
  ->package
    ->java classes
properties
  ->properties file
```

The properties file (from external vendor), needs to be placed in a specific location - and I am not sure how to generate this with ANT and INNO.

The resulting file structure needs to look like this

```
app folder
  ->exe
    runtime
    app
    ->libs
      properties
        ->server.properties
      app.cfg
      app.jar
```

I am not really sure how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the `[Files]` section with `Source` and `DestDir` might work out here.

There are two (or even more) ways to do this:

You may prepare the directory structure beforehand with `ant`.
That means you create the folder structure present after installation utilizing `ant` on your machine and tell Innosetup to include all files and folders and just extract them.

```
[Files]
Source: "x:\app folder\*"; DestDir: "{app}";
```

Or you work with your project folder structure and tell Innosetup to include your files from their specific locations in the project and copy them to specific destination directories.

```
[Files]
Source: "x:\project\properties\properties.xml"; DestDir: "{app}\app\properties\";
```

Comment: This answer pointed me to the steps needed to solve this issue.  I needed to ensure that the properties folder was copied to external folder during the ant build, then deployed with INNO.  Thanks.